# Override GNOME 3's Slow Screen-Lock Recovery

Tags: gnome, suspend, lock-screen, 19.10

In Ubuntu 19.10, I have "Screen-Lock" turned off:
[image]

However, the desktop still goes into the same state it would if "Screen-Lock" were turned on; the only difference is: you don't have to type in your password to unlock it (you can just press the enter-key instead).

I'm looking for a work-around to two issues:

1. Recovery from Screen Lock takes too long. It takes the amount of
   you might expect recovering from a suspended state, however, it takes way longer than you'd expect from lock-state recovery (which I
   expect to be instant). Since Screen-Lock>Off doesn't prevent going
   into this state, how can I replace this feature with a traditional
   screen-lock, one where recovery is instantaneous.
2. I want the ability to unlock my screen by moving my mouse.

Comment: I submitted a bug [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-control-center/issues/757).

Comment: Still, no one has offered a workaround. Maybe someone on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/eocpga/unnecessary_delays_recovering_from_screen_lock/) will have a suggestion.

Comment: This [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1832812) also seems related.